# ViewModelProvider java.lang.ClassCastException when changing from debug to release variant

Tags: java, android, viewmodel, viewmodelproviders

I'm trying to build a application from my company but when I change the build variant to release (the variant only changes the project configuration files, like endpoints and credentials), I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.timo.ecocloud.paciente, PID: 15435
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.timo.ecocloud.paciente/com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.ui.login.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
    at android.support.v4.media.session.b.a(SourceFile:1)
    at j1.a.<init>(SourceFile:1)
    at com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.ui.login.f.a(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.lifecycle.s.b(SourceFile:1)
    at androidx.lifecycle.s.a(SourceFile:1)
    at com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:68)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)    
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

The piece of code which generates the error is this:

```
loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LoginViewModelFactory())
                .get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

I've tried updating everything, even using the more updated version:

```
new ViewModelProvider(this, new LoginViewModelFactory()).get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

But nothing has worked so far, did anyone know how to solve this?

Edit: viewmodel, viewmodelfactory codes below:
In the activity (the code that generates the error)

```
loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LoginViewModelFactory())
                .get(LoginViewModel.class);
```

LoginViewModel.java:

```
package com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.ui.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Patterns;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.data.LoginRepository;
import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.R;
import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.model.DefaultResponse;
import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.model.DefaultResponseResult;
import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.model.User;

public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<LoginFormState> loginFormState = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<RecoverFormState> recoverFormState = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private MutableLiveData<LoginResult> loginResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MutableLiveData<DefaultResponseResult> defaultResult = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;

    LoginViewModel(LoginRepository loginRepository) {
        this.loginRepository = loginRepository;
    }


    /**
     * Login
     */

    LiveData<LoginFormState> getLoginFormState() {
        return loginFormState;
    }

    LiveData<LoginResult> getLoginResult() {
        return loginResult;
    }

    public void login(String username, String password) {
        // can be launched in a separate asynchronous job
        loginRepository.login(username, password, this);
    }

    public void loginDataChanged(String username, String password) {
        if (!isUserNameValid(username)) {
            loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(R.string.login_invalid_username, null));
        } else if (!isPasswordValid(password)) {
            loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(null, R.string.login_invalid_password));
        } else {
            loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(true));
        }
    }

    // A placeholder username validation check
    private boolean isUserNameValid(String username) {
        return username != null && !username.equals("");
    }

    // A placeholder password validation check
    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        return password != null && password.trim().length() == 6;
    }

    /**
     * Used for callback
     */
    public void onSuccess(User user) {
        loginResult.setValue(new LoginResult(user));
    }

    public void onError(String message) {
        loginResult.setValue(new LoginResult(message));
    }

    /**
     * Recover password
     */
    LiveData<RecoverFormState> getRecoverFormState() {
        return recoverFormState;
    }

    public void recoverDataChanged(String useremail) {

        if (!isEmailValid(useremail)) {
            recoverFormState.setValue(new RecoverFormState(R.string.recover_invalid_email));
        }else {
            recoverFormState.setValue(new RecoverFormState(true));
        }
    }

    LiveData<DefaultResponseResult> getDefaultResult() {
        return defaultResult;
    }

    public void recoverPwd(Activity activity, LoginViewModel loginViewModel, String email){
        loginRepository.recoverPwd(activity, loginViewModel,  email);
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email){
        if (email == null || email.trim().isEmpty())
           return false;

        if (email.contains("@"))
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        else
            return false;
    }


    /**
     * Used for callback
     */
    public void defaultReturnOnSuccess(DefaultResponse defaultResponse) {
        defaultResult.setValue(new DefaultResponseResult(defaultResponse, ""));
    }

    public void defaultReturnOnError(String message) {
        defaultResult.setValue(new DefaultResponseResult(message));
    }
}
```

LoginViewModelFactory.java

```
package com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.ui.login;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.data.LoginDataSource;
import com.timo.ecocloudpaciente.data.LoginRepository;
public class LoginViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(LoginViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new LoginViewModel(LoginRepository.getInstance(new LoginDataSource()));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually such problems can be attributed to obfuscation of the code by `proguard`. From the code you shared, it's not clear why proguard can't handle the class name change correctly. Are you sure you are not using somewhere in the code the class name as a string instead of `MyClass.class`? In any case, just edit the `proguard-rules.pro` file to add the class you want to keep, for example, `-keep class my.package.MyClass`.

Comment: @anemomylos I've added all my viewmodel classes to proguard with the "-keep class" but the error continues, and I dont use my class name as a string, i've checked everywhere.
For now I can have the proguard disabled at least

Comment: You could get a better answer by adding the code of the activity and the factory.

Comment: Files added to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you recently upgraded your AGP to 8.+

just add this line to your gradle.properties file

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=false
```